# How could people handle arachnophobia in a world where spiders have the size of pets?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, science-fiction, xenobiology, aliens

I am thinking about an alien planet where most species of spiders are the size of cats and dogs and the biggest of the most rare species are the size of a car. In this world there is the same technology and scientific level as nowadays but since spiders have an alien and bizarre faces and appearance( in my opinion of course as I saw many closeups of spiders on Google) arachnofobia is the norm.

How could people get used with giant spiders since old times considering that most species are not poisonous and the square cube law would probably make them impossible to jump several times their own size and be relatively slow?

Comment: I downvoted because it was trivial to look up [Cynophobia](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/22082-cynophobia-fear-of-dogs) (an irrational fear of dogs) and start reading about how people deal with it. Note that the Q could be closed for needing more focus as it asks multiple questions (you're supposed to ask only one).

Comment: So, in other words, you are introducing a major change in the surrounding world, a change that was *always* there, but assume that people have the same mental biases as in our world. This is extremely unlikely. (And anyway, lots of people have an irrational fear of snakes, [ophidiophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophidiophobia). This is actually *the* most common phobia, affecting up to one third of humans. How do we deal with it? We kill the snakes. In most places where humans live, snakes have a precarious existence. Same with your spiders. Humans are good at killing things.)

Comment: Snakes in our world go from the size of large insects, to the size of pets to sizes longer than any human. Said snakes go from completely harmless to fully capable of overpowering the strongest humans. At the same time, In our world, we have people who have an irrational fear of even the most harmless and smallest snake and others who [joyfully explain how some of them could easily kill you while holding one of said snakes in a video about having them as pets](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wbOx_UqXaE4). Is there any reason you'd think it'd be different if the same was true for spiders?

Comment: What might help focus the question would be if you were to bring in how [exposure therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_therapy) might play out, and how to accomplish it.

Comment: I wouldn't do any of that. If they are cat sized they can do like cats and run fast and leap many times their body length or height.

Answer (score 3):

How could people get used with giant spiders ?

Buy a gun, it's legal to shoot any animal in self defense, no guns in your world? use crossbows.... no crossbows in your world? use slings... slings are too advanced... use the mightiest weapon for self defense of all, throw a rock in the middle of their cranium.

Or as other's made the example of people having phobias for dogs, or just a healthy dislike for noisy and smelly barking furry things that pee and poo everywhere... buy a dog whistle.

Alternativelly for spiders, use UV lights that can burn their eyes to charcoal, yes spiders are very sensitivie to UV lights, fun fact... they don't even have eyelids to close their eyes, so if you point a torch at them, you are literally frying their eyes.

As a rule of thumb the healthiest activity ever done by any human ever, the same activity that brought us to our top notch high level of technology  and helped us survive all that time, is the activity of killing everything that scares us.

There's nothing healthier than killing things down before they kill you.

You are ''somethingphobic'' ? just kill it, burn it with fire, shoot it down... kill your fears, not poethically, kill them for real.

Like for real, killing things is the only innate talent of human beings, even a child can kill, and for good reason, if you fear something, just kill it.

just kill it!

[image]

You see a big stupid ugly spider? throw a rock in his big stupid ugly eyes, scream, and without elaborating further just run away and let the spider die bleeding from his eyes.

Alternativelly.... :

[image]

Another fun fact, spiders are so stupid they haven't even figured out muscels, they use blood pressure to move around... if you poke a hole inside of them, all that pressure is lost and they lose the strength needed to walk around.

Comment: I should make a book on how to kill various fantasy things, it might be fun... maybe a documentary is better.

Answer (score 0):

### Less arachnophobia, more well-grounded fear and still a nuisance

**The slow speed makes big spiders move less unexpected and uncontrollable**

Arachnophobia is irrational fear of spiders. They jump around etc.. These big spiders won't jump around and escape your view all the time. Suppose most spiders don't bite. You push it away and it will walk out, go somewhere else. Humans won't irrationally *panic* when they see a spider, like they do in our world where little spiders suddenly appear, move quick and seemingly uncontrollable.

There's less irrational fear and more real fear. Like you don't want a spider to bite you, or to have a big spider (even one !) inside the house. People will still want to get rid of spiders, in most circumstances. Kill them or chase them away.

Spiders are mainly wild animals now.. How would they thrive in your world, some ideas

**Spiders in the wild**

Most of your spiders would live elsewhere, nowhere near humans. They like caves. There will be less tourists in these caves. Spiders don't do much to humans, humans are mainly ignored by spiders, but they bump into you sometimes and they are slimy. Humans and free spiders don't prefer living together.

**Spiders are no pets**

Somehow humans and spiders avoid eachother. I don't think giant spiders will turn into pets. They may be put to work, or they are wild animals, sometimes *plague animals* and treated as such.

**Some will be cattle ?**

Part of your spiders may get domesticated. Spiders can be manipulated (with food) to build webs for construction. You could harvest spider milk, pigments, or spider venom, or use the silk material for other purposes.. or breed certain types of spiders for their meat. Maybe these big, slow spiders would behave like goats, or ostriches. Feed them, their backs taste like shrimp steak, humans will serve spider back in all restaurants on the planet.

**The webs hinder traffic**

One nasty habit of these big spiders is really really a nuisance: their webs. They get killed for that, especially in cities. You've got [garden scissors](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=garden%20scissors) to free your parking place, but spiders can make webs everywhere. In the open, these webs, or cables can be dangerous when it hangs  over a road. Transport in your world has protective fronts to withstand the collision. I have to hand-waive how that would all work out, but chance is, there is no easy traffic, because of the spider webs..

**And *some* spiders.. you'll be afraid, as you are now**

[image]
Bird eater

Humans have one advantage over spiders now: size. But the real dangerous ones can [kill us with venom](https://www.inverse.com/science/notorious-aussie-spider-kills-humans-via-evolutionary-coincidence). There will be less need for venom, when a spider is bigger, but you don't want to meet a spider larger than you, with pointy claws and beak.

The same species *all* humans are afraid of now, we will have to be afraid of then.. Tarantula may be a [popular pet](https://www.google.com/search?q=tarantula%20pet%20to%20humans) for some students, but for a car-sized Tarantula, humans better hide in the closet !